# About Next.js Router: router.events scrollRestoration didn't work

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router, infinite-scroll, next-router

I'm very curious why it doesn't work...

my next.js version is 12.2.5 and react version is 17.0.2
and I want to creat code that performs the following actions:

1.The user is viewing the post list and clicks on the post details in the list to enter.
2. When user press the back button, move to the after list location. (like (top: x, left:y)

I'm running a service, and I'm running into a problem where it works well in stage and local environments, but doesn't work well in the live environment.

and first, this is my custom hook about ScrollRestoration

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function useScrollRestoration() {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const saveScrollPostion = () => {
      const scrollPosition = {
        x: window.scrollX,
        y: window.scrollY,
      };
      sessionStorage.setItem(
        `next_scroll_${router.asPath}`,
        JSON.stringify(scrollPosition),
      );
    };

    const restoreScrollPosition = () => {
      const _scroll = sessionStorage.getItem(`next_scroll_${router.asPath}`);

      if (_scroll) {
        const { x, y } = JSON.parse(_scroll);
        window.scrollTo(x, y);
      }
    };

    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', saveScrollPostion);
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', restoreScrollPosition);

    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeStart', saveScrollPostion);
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', restoreScrollPosition);
    };
  }, [router]);
}
```

and also, I already add to next.config.js to this code

```
const nextConfig = {
  onDemandEntries: {
    scroll: true,
  },
```

Any idea why these don't work only in a live environment?
I'm not sure if it's a problem with next.js Router or Server environment...

I need advice desperately about this problem ;( how can i resolve?